# Python - How to get an attribute of a derived class using a method in the base class

Tags: python, inheritance, class-attributes

Let's say I have a Dog class that inherits from an Animal class. I want every Animal to make a noise of some sort, and I want to be able to access this noise using a method, regardless of whether an instance of the animal exists.

This is essentially what I want: (I get `NameError: name 'noise' is not defined` when I try to run it)

```
class Animal:
    noise = ''
    def get_noise():
        return noise

class Dog(Animal):
    noise = 'Woof!'

Dog.get_noise()
```

I know I can just call `Dog.noise` to do the same thing, but I'd like to know how to do it using a method, if possible. I also know I could just create a `get_noise` method inside `Dog` and return `Dog.noise` but it seems inelegant to create this method for every type of animal rather than just inherit from the `Animal` class.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Likely you want `.get_noise()` on an instance, not on the class function. So answers are nice, but question can be wrong. Maybe you want `adog = Dog(); adog.get_noise(); `

Comment: @sherdim I want to know a priori what noise an animal will make, before any instances are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
@classmethod
def get_noise(cls):
    return cls.noise
```

You need `classmethod` to properly make the method callable from both instances and classes, and it also conveniently passes in the current class from which you can access the `.noise` attribute.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I saw this syntax on another website, but I didn't fully understand it. I see now that cls is a keyword that refers to the class, like self refers to the instance.

It also seems that you can miss out the @classmethod decorator if you call Dog.get_noise(Dog) rather than Dog.get_noise().

Comment: @moonybaby Niether `cls` nor `self` are keywords. They are just conventions.

Comment: Interesting, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

The following worked for me.

```
class Animal:
    noise = 'Noise'

    def get_noise(self):
        return self.noise


class Dog(Animal):
    noise = 'Woof!'


dog = Dog()
dog.get_noise()
```

Comment: The question asks "regardless of whether an instance of the animal exists". So this solution doesn't solve that problem.

Comment: You are right. I missed that.